# Passing properties as arguments while setting other properties of same object

Tags: javascript, raphael, javascript-objects

I'm using Raphael.js to make a little JS game. This is my first big project in JS, so I'm not familiar with all the design patterns and such. I'm trying to make an object that represents a move timer. Starting at line "litCircle", I get errors:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property '0' of undefined
```

c is my Raphael object. Is there something I don't know about, where you can't use the properties of the object you're currently defining in function calls that you're using to help set the values of the object's other properties?

```
var moveTimer = {
  mtScaler : 15,
  all : c.set(),
  RS : [1*this.mtScaler,3*this.mtScaler,4*this.mtScaler],
  litCircle : c.circle(200,37,this.RS[0]),
  midCircle : c.circle(200,37,this.RS[1]).attr({
    "stroke-dasharray": "- "
  }),
  bigCircle : c.circle(200,37,this.RS[2]).attr({
    "stroke-dasharray":". "}),
  orangeOne : c.circle(200, 37,this.RS[0]).attr({
    "stroke-width": 2,
    "stroke": COLOR_DICT["orange"],
  }),
  turnCounter : c.text(200,38,0),
  orangeAnim :
    Raphael.animation({
      "50%": { r: this.RS[2] },
      "100%": {  r: this.RS[0] }
    }, 3000),
  finish : function(){
    this.all.push(this.litCircle, this.midCircle, this.bigCircle,
      this.orangeOne, this.turnCounter);
    this.all.transform("t250,230");
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

RS is still being defined at the time you are calling it, define some variables outside of definition and utilize those.

Example:

```
var scaler, rs;
scaler = 15;
rs = [1*tscaler,3*tscaler,4*scaler];

var moveTimer = {
  mtScaler : scaler,
  all : c.set(),
  RS : rs,
  litCircle : c.circle(200,37,rs[0]),
  midCircle : c.circle(200,37,rs[1]).attr({
    "stroke-dasharray": "- "
  }),
  bigCircle : c.circle(200,37,this.RS[2]).attr({
    "stroke-dasharray":". "}),
  orangeOne : c.circle(200, 37,this.RS[0]).attr({
    "stroke-width": 2,
    "stroke": COLOR_DICT["orange"],
  }),
  turnCounter : c.text(200,38,0),
  orangeAnim :
    Raphael.animation({
      "50%": { r: this.RS[2] },
      "100%": {  r: this.RS[0] }
    }, 3000),
  finish : function(){
    this.all.push(this.litCircle, this.midCircle, this.bigCircle,
      this.orangeOne, this.turnCounter);
    this.all.transform("t250,230");
  }
}
```

> This may not be 100% since I can't confirm the code, but is a starting place.

Answer (score 1):

That `this` at `litCircle : c.circle(200,37,this.RS[0])`
means the caller, `Window` object, not `moveTimer` you defined.

Obviously, `Window` object does not have the property `RS`.

Comment: If you do not prefer declare global variable, you can define a constructor to generate the movetimer object.
Maybe like:
function generateMoveTimer() {
    this.mtScaler = 15;
    this.RS = [1 * this.mtScaler, 2 * this.mtScaler, 2 * this.mtScaler, ];
    ...
}
var moveTimer = new generateMoveTimer();